# Linq to MongoDB Filter

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-query, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have a MongoDB collection, listed below:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("001"), 
    "ticker" : "MSFT=US", 
    "exchange" : "OTC", 
    "localtick" : "MSFT", 
    "compname" : "Microsoft", 
    "currency" : "USD", 
    "insertedtime" : ISODate("2016-06-13T23:10:09.341+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("002"), 
    "ticker" : "TSLA=CA", 
    "exchange" : "TSX", 
    "localtick" : "TSLA", , 
    "compname" : "Tesla", 
    "currency" : "CAD", 
    "insertedtime" : ISODate("2016-06-13T23:10:09.809+0000")
}
```

But when I try to do a filter in my query:

```
var documents = collection.AsQueryable()
            .Where(c => c["ticker"].ToString().Contains("=CA"));
```

I get the following error:

```
Unsupported filter: {document}{ticker}.ToString().Contains("=CA").
```

What should I be doing to get MongoDB to handshake with LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a strongly-typed collection when using LINQ queries:

```
public class Test
{
    public ObjectId _id;
    public string ticker;
    public string exchange;
    public string localtick;
    public string compname;
    public string currency;
    public DateTime insertedtime;
}

var query = db.GetCollection<Test>("test")
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where(c => c.ticker.Contains("=CA"));
```