# Linq to MongoDB Filter without strong typing

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-query

My question is similar to the following except that given answer there doesn't work for me:
[Linq to MongoDB Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800826/linq-to-mongodb-filter)

My documents have a lot of elements. I tried to create a class with only some of the elements defined (as below) but that's not working.

```
public class Test
{
    public ObjectId _id;
    public string ticker;
}
```

I get an error that there are other elements that do not match any field in the class.

Is there any way to avoid strong typing? Not all documents in my collection have the same set of elements, so the union of all elements is too much.

Thanks

Comment: I found the answer here :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448634/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-ignore-fields-on-binding

Comment: mention link in the answer section, so that everyone can know..